# Rails nested Resources Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this nested recourses

```
  resources :products do
     resources :senders
  end
```

In my products/index view I have this

```
...
..
.
<td><%= link_to 'Show Email Addresses', product_senders_path(product) %> </td>
.
..
...
```

which seemed to be working and it redirected me to the senders of that product. Now for some strange reason I get this:

```
 NameError in Senders#index

undefined local variable or method `sender_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003cb1f58>:0x00000003b46e48>

Extracted source (around line #18):

15:     <td><%= sender.product_id %></td>
16:     <td><%= sender.name %></td>
17:     <td><%= sender.email %></td>
18:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', sender %></td>
19:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sender_path(sender) %></td>
20:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sender, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
21:   </tr>
```

This is my sender/index file:

```
<h1>Listing senders</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Application</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @senders.each do |sender| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= sender.product_id %></td>
    <td><%= sender.name %></td>
    <td><%= sender.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', sender %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sender_path(sender) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sender, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
```

Why I am getting this error? Before it was working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are only nested routes for senders, there are no `edit_sender_path(sender)` helper, only `edit_product_sender_path(product, sender)`

You may see a list of all application route helpers by executing `rake routes`

Comment: hey thanks, now its seems to work, but the thing is that each time I try to create a sender, the sender gets created, I just get a routing error! any ideas? thanks!